# Change marker icon in geoJSON using sheetsee.js and mapbox

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, marker, geojson, mapbox

So, this guy created [a JavaScript function to change marker icon of geoJSON](http://bl.ocks.org/geografa/8743008) in mapbox map.

I tried to apply his function for [my map](http://www.g-base.com/sk/mapbox/krcmy/krcmy.html), which is generating geoJSON from a Google spreadsheet using sheetsee.js and mapbox/leaflet. I want to change default grey icons for my own image but my re-writing attempt of his function to my map didn't work.

I'm not very skilled in JavaScript so I would be very glad for any hints what I did wrong.

Comment: Could you show what your re-writing attempt looks like ?